# css text-right wont work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Can you help me to understand why my `h1` and `h3` headline wont align
right even though it is in the html code (line 10 - 13)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6"><img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
        <h1>Jane Doette</h1>
        <h3>Front-end Ninja</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="row">
.......
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/MLuMHYa59a)

Comment: Note that HTML does not align text, but CSS does. However, I think your bootstrap is not loaded fully, rendering the class useless.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle of your code https://jsfiddle.net/kg0eLsqf/1/ look like its working. The only issue i see is an extra closing </div> at the end but that is not the problem

Comment: Use this as the bootstrap css resource instead
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

Answer (score 3):

I think the text-right is supposed to be used with text-taggs like: `<h1 class="text-right">Jane Doette</h1>`

The source is here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment

[Here is a link to a fiddle as wel](https://jsfiddle.net/1bqmgLkf/4/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12335642)

Comment: I did actually include a piece of code that would solve the question, and the link is from bootstrap's homepage, I thought it might be useful to add.

And to those who think adding `text-align: right;` to the div, that's exactly what the class text-right does in bootstrap.

As @Johannes said in another answer here the h1 and h3 are block elements and have 100% width, and the text is aligned to the left, unless it's specified in CSS or a style-tag.

Comment: `.text-right` uses `text-align` property, which is inherited.

Answer (score -1):

**Bootstrap can be annoying sometimes.**

Try using some css. Change

```
  <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
    <h1>Jane Doette</h1>
    <h3>Front-end Ninja</h3>
  </div>
```

to:

```
  <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align:right;">
    <h1>Jane Doette</h1>
    <h3>Front-end Ninja</h3>
  </div>
```

Example fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/1bqmgLkf/

Comment: Sefan is using bootstrap css which has a class text-right defined, see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment